# Does Protractor support returning Promises in tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise, protractor

Some test suites support returning Promises in tests to trigger an asynchronous test. The following example would result in a test that passes after 2 seconds if I were using Mocha:

```
it('async test', function() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
}
```

As far as I can tell, Protractor uses Jasmine and Jasmine doesn't document that it supports this behavior. Yet if I do this in Protractor, it *does* work like Mocha does. I know Protractor modifies Jasmine behavior, like making `expect(...)` wait for Promises, but I can't find any documentation for the above behavior.

What is the source that supports the above behavior? Is it Jasmine, Protractor, or maybe even Selenium? And where is the documentation for this behavior?